# SQL Query List of months between dates

Tags: sql, date

I've been searching without success for a way to list the months where my tables entries are in use.

Let's say we have a table with items in use between two dates :

```
ID   StartDate   EndDate as ItemsInUse

A   01.01.2013   31.03.2013
B   01.02.2013   30.04.2013
C   01.05.2013   31.05.2013
```

I need a way to query that table and return something like :

```
ID  Month
A   01
A   02
A   03
B   02
B   03
B   04
C   05
```

I'm really stuck with this. Does anyone have any clues on doing this ?

PS : European dates formats ;-)

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [calendar table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/70482/) then

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.Id, c.Month
  FROM Calendar c
  JOIN ItemsInUse i 
    ON c.ShortDate BETWEEN i.StartDate AND i.EndDate
```

Comment: Have a look at my solution, which achieves the same thing, but doesn't use a calendar table...

Answer (score 1):

Here should be the answer:

```
select ID, 
       ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN('31.03.2013','01.01.2013')) "MONTHS" 
from TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are padded in the way you suggest - i.e. where one digit days or months have an initial 0 - you can just use the `SUBSTRING` function as in:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(StartDate, 3, 2) ...
```

Alternatively, if you do not have the padding you can use:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(StartDate, '.',2), '.', -1) ...
```

(This latter command is in two parts.  The inner `SUBSTRING_INDEX` generates a string containing your day and month, and the outer `SUBSTRING_INDEX` takes the month.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `MONTH()` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

```
SELECT ID, MONTH(StartDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Dare say this can be improved on, but as a rough 'n' ready (assuming ms-sql)

```
create table #results (ID varchar(10), Month int, Year int);

declare @ID varchar(10);
declare @StartDate datetime;
declare @EndDate datetime;

declare myCursor cursor for select [ID], [StartDate],[EndDate] from ItemsInUse;
open myCursor;
delete from #results;
fetch next from myCursor into @ID, @StartDate, @EndDate;
declare @tempDate datetime;
 while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @tempdate = CAST( CAST(year(@StartDate) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(@StartDate) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(1 AS varchar) AS DATETIME);
    while @tempDate < @EndDate
    begin
        insert into #results values (@ID, MONTH(@tempDate), YEAR(@tempDate));
        set @tempDate = DATEADD(month,1,@tempdate);
    end

    fetch next from myCursor into @ID, @StartDate, @EndDate;
end

close myCursor;
deallocate myCursor;

select * from #results;
drop table #results;
```